# Change, error response displays a single error message in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using **required_without** validation for required any one field.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'user_email' => 'required_without:user_phone|email',
            'user_phone' => 'required_without:user_email|min:10',
            'country_code' => 'required_with:user_phone',           
            'otp' => 'required|numeric|max:6',
        ]);
```

**And How to user Unique for check email or phone registered or not in my tbl_users**

And I have got this error message,I want to display one one line for **user_email** or **user_phone**.
And I am using country_code if user_phone.

I have got these error messages in response.

```
{
    "user_email": [
        "The user email field is required when user phone is not present."
    ],
    "user_phone": [
        "The user phone field is required when user email is not present."
    ]
}
```

i want this type of error message with s, Like :

```
{ 
 "status":false,
 "message":"Please enter email or phone"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third param to add message manually, remove `required_without` for `user_email` and keep it for `user_phone`

```
   $messages = [
        'user_phone.required_without' => 'Please enter email or phone',
   ]

   return Validator::make($data, [
        'user_email' => 'user_phone|email',
        'user_phone' => 'required_without:user_email|min:10',
        'country_code' => 'required_with:user_phone',           
        'otp' => 'required|numeric|max:6',
    ],$messages);
```

Now you will get error message for only `user_phone` as `Please enter email or phone`